# Como ignorar el prefix en un comando especifico de Discord Js

Tags: nodejs

tengo una siguiente duda, estoy desarrollando un bot para dar auto-rol haciendo una verificación en una tabla excel, el problema que tengo es que yo creo un canal privado para ese usuario para que pueda interactuar con el bot y pueda enviar sus datos de forma privada, hasta allí funciona todo bien, el inconveniente es que el bot ignora todo tipo de mensaje que no contenga el prefix (!) y el comando con el que se ejecuto, ósea que hay que escribir (!rol argumento) para que el bot responda a lo cual yo necesito que ignore eso y solo capte los mensajes, existe alguna forma de ignorar el prefix para ese comando especifico?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es muy fácil por ejemplo;

```
(Con prefix) - `if (message.content.startsWith("!hola")` solo responderá al comando `!hola`.

(Sin prefix) - `if (message.content.startsWith("hola")` el bot contestará al comando `hola.`
```

Aquí te dejo el script básico con el ejemplo de arriba completo.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();


client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("¡BOT listo!");
 });

 client.on("message", (message) => {
   if(message.content.startsWith("Hola")) {
     message.channel.send("¡Hola!");
   }
    }});
client.login("ESCRIBE_AQUÍ_EL_TOKEN_DE_TÚ_BOT");
```